# Cannot read images from Tensorflow.js Tensorcamera on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, expo, tensorflow.js

I am trying to use Tensorflow.js posenet on React Native but I can not get 'images'. 
Currently Expo-camera works ok, but images is undefined, and it also shows

> Can't find variable: React

Please advise how to iterate getting images from TensorCamera.
Thanks

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { cameraWithTensors } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
import * as posenet from '@tensorflow-models/posenet';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCameraStream = this.handleCameraStream.bind(this);
  }

  async estimatePoseOnImage(imageElement) {
    const net = await posenet.load();
    const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
      flipHorizontal: false,
    });
    this.setState({ pose: pose });
    return pose;
  }

  handleCameraStream( images ) {
    const loop = async () => {
      const nextImageTensor = await images.next().value;
      await this.estimatePoseOnImage(nextImageTensor);
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    loop();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TensorCamera
          type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
          onReady={this.handleCameraStream}
          autorender={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the code of `cameraWithTensors` ?

Comment: It is imported like ```import { cameraWithTensors } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';```

Comment: If images is undefined, it might depend on how you are calling the `handleCameraStream` in `TensorCamera`. If you can make a snippet demonstrating your error, it will be easier to spot the mistake and fix it

Comment: It also shows like this >  Can't find variable: React

Comment: Did you follow official docs on how to install react and react-native ?

Comment: @edkeveked I think react and react-native installation is correct, because it works fine on the other pages that those are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TensorCamera
    ref={(ref) => { this.camera = ref }}
    type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
    resizeHeight={64}
    resizeWidth={64}
    resizeDepth={3}
    onReady={this.handleCameraStream}
    style={{width: width, height: height}}
/>
```

You have to pass resizeHeight, resizeWidth, resizeDepth to get the tensor. It worked for me.